# How to Dynamically assign value to Dojo's object

Tags: dojo

I am tring to implement TooltipDialog with Dojo, Although the dialog shows up great,But I still have no idea how to change the content of the tip, I have code as following:

```
var _tipContent;

require([
        "dijit/TooltipDialog",
        "dijit/popup",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (TooltipDialog, popup, on, dom) {
        var myTooltipDialog = new TooltipDialog({
            id: 'myTooltipDialog',
            style: "width: 300px;",
            content: _tipContent,
            onMouseLeave: function () {
                popup.close(myTooltipDialog);
            }
        });

        on(dom.byId('TriggerBlock'), 'mouseover', function () {
            popup.open({
                popup: myTooltipDialog,
                around: dom.byId('TriggerBlock')
            });
        });
    });

function onMouseOverGraphics(sender, eventArgs) {
  _tipContent = "I wanna change the tip's content according to the current position, the x coordinate: " + eventArgs.clientX;
```

}

Comment: `myTooltipDialog.set("content", theContent)` The variable scope should be considered in your situation.

Comment: thanks xyu!it works well.I am wondering whether the all of object's method can using 'set' to assign value.

Comment: Didn't quite understand, but you can use `widget.set('property', value)` to set most of the properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead:

```
dijit.showTooltip("This is the tool tip content",
     //this is the dom where you want the tooltip to show
     select.domNode,
     //this is an attribute to get where the tooltip of the dom
     select.get('tooltipPosition'),
     //this is the position or the side of where the tooltip will sho
     !select.isLeftToRight()
     );
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,Krishna, I can't find the method through API Reference of the official website, Maybe the your code belong to prior version, I am working on 1.9.1

Comment: i am also working on 1.9.1 but sometimes if you write your code with the old version syntax it works fine, i guess dojo developers try to keep everyone happy, even on new version. it might be deprecated but it still works. btw i read your question again it seems that i miss understand you. what you nee is simple just do `registry.byId("myTooltipDialog").set("content","here is the new content")` ofcourse you need to add the `"dijit/registry"` in your require